# What is meant by a pass in an Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I have came across a practice question from **GATE PYQ's.**
The question asks about the **pass** in merge sort sorting algorithm.
Below is the question:

If one uses straight two-way merge sort algorithm to sort the following elements in ascending order:

```
 20, 47, 15, 8, 9, 4, 40, 30, 12, 17
```

then the order of these elements after second pass of the algorithm is:

A) 8, 9, 15, 20, 47, 4, 12, 17, 30, 40

**B) 8, 15, 20, 47, 4, 9, 30, 40, 12, 17** **[CORRECT OPTION]**

C) 15, 20, 47, 4, 8, 9, 12, 30, 40, 17

D) 4, 8, 9, 15, 20, 47, 12, 17, 30, 40

I am just not able find out what is meant by pass and how to find it in this case.

Distribution of elements in the recursive calls:

```
         20, 37, 15, 8, 9, 4, 40, 30, 12, 17
                 /                 \
        20, 47, 15, 8, 9       4, 40, 30, 12, 17
       /        \                     /          \
 20, 47, 15     8, 9              4, 40, 30      12, 17
    /    \
20, 47   15
```

After sorting:

```
           4 ,8, 9, 15, 12, 17, 20, 30, 40, 47 
                 /                     \
     8, 9, 15, 20, 47               4, 12, 17, 30, 40
       /        \                     /          \
 20, 15, 47     8, 9              4, 30, 40      12, 17
    /    \
20, 47   15
```

Comment: A pass is one loop through the code.

Comment: googling gives [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pV2IF0fgKY&t=857). he gets to the "passes" soon enough.

Comment: you're welcome. :) happy lucubrations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the term pass implies that the question is asking about bottom up merge sort which starts by treating an array of n elements as n runs of size 1. Each pass merges even and odd runs, doubling the size of runs (except for the last run which may be shorter). The sort is done when run size >= number of elements.

```
|20|47|15| 8| 9| 4|40|30|12|17|   start
|20 47| 8 15| 4  9|30 40|12 17|   after pass 1
| 8 15 20 47| 4  9 30 40|12 17|   after pass 2
| 4  8  9 15 20 30 40 47|12 17|   after pass 3
| 4  8  9 12 15 17 20 30 40 47|   after pass 4, done
```

Comment: how will it group if there are odd number of elements ?

Comment: @SohamShinde - the last run may only have 1 element. Worst case is when the number of elements is 2^n+1, in which case that single element is not merged until the very last pass that merges a run with 2^n elements with the 1 element. One common method used to improve this is to use insertion sort to create sorted runs of 32 or 64 elements, before starting the bottom up merge sort.